# Typescript, Unit Tests: Correct typing for Dispatching a Thunk with store.dispatch from redux-mock-store

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, redux, redux-mock-store

Is there any way to correctly dispatch a Thunk from a store created with redux-mock-store ? Right now I am forced to use any type assertion

```
store.dispatch<any>(getCommissions());
```

As `dispatch` expects to provide plain Action

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IRootState, undefined, 
AnyAction>, getState: () => IRootState) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IRootState, undefined, AnyAction>, getState: () => IRootState) => void'.
```

Code fragment for `getCommisions()`

```
export function getCommissions() {
  return (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IRootState, undefined, AnyAction>, getState: () => IRootState) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 24):

The `createMockStore` function that is the default export of `redux-mock-store` accepts generic types `<S, DispatchExts>` where `S` is the definition of your Redux state, and `DispatchExts`is a union of (or single) additional `Dispatch` signatures for any added Redux middleware.

So the way to set this up is to import `ThunkDispatch` from `redux-thunk`, which accepts its own generic arguments of `<State, ExtraArgument, Action>` and pass that in as the `DispatchExts` argument to `createMockStore`.

Here's an abbreviated example:

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux'; // Or your own Action definition
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

import { ApplicationState } from '../your/definitions';

type DispatchExts = ThunkDispatch<ApplicationState, void, AnyAction>;

const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = createMockStore<ApplicationState, DispatchExts>(middleware);

const store = mockStore();
```

Hope that helps you!

My current versions:
`redux 4.0.0`
`redux-thunk 2.3.0`
`redux-mock-store 1.5.3`
`typescript 2.9.2`

`ThunkDispatch` defintion https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/index.d.ts

`createMockStore` definition https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-mock-store/index.d.ts

Comment: what about configureMockStore?

Answer (score 7):

For `configureMockStore` use, the solution is almost exactly the same as the answer by @nickpassarella.

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { MyState, MyActions } from './my-types';

type DispatchExts = ThunkDispatch<MyState, undefined, MyActions>;

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore<MyState, DispatchExts>(middlewares);

const store = mockStore();
```

Both examples working with `redux 4.0.1` `redux-thunk 2.3.0` `redux-mock-store 1.5.3` and `typescript 3.5.3`

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I found a more up to date fork of the library written in Typescript and works better with latest versions of the redux (`4.0.4`) and redux-thunk `2.3.0`.

https://github.com/jedmao/redux-mock-store